# Extract email from excel spreadsheet

Tags: email, spreadsheet

[Excel spreadsheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BVyd.png)

I would like to extract the email addresses from this spreadsheet and put them in a separate column that corresponds to the Senator's name.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried already? Is the format always "senator.<name.@aph.gov.au"?

Comment: Yes, Robin. The format is always senator <name>@aph.gov.au. I have tried concatenating the fields, but as the senators are listed by last name and then first name, it became a bit complicated. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

in E1 put

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(D1,FIND(" ",D1&" ",FIND("@",A2))-1)," ",REPT(" ",LEN(D1))),LEN(D1))),0)
```